# API Call Returns Data But Not Render

Tags: reactjs

My console.log shows axios call returns data [object object] but it shows undefined when I try to render the data. Any ideas?

````
```
class CourseDetail extends Component {
          state={
             ID: this.props.match.params.ID,
             course:[]};
            componentDidMount(){
              this.runSearch();

           }

           runSearch=async()=>{

             const response= await axios.get('API\?{this.props.match.params.ID}')
             this.setState({course: response.data});
            //console.log shows course=[object object]
             console.log("course="+response.data);
           }
        render(){
           //course is undefined below

        const course= this.state.course.map(item=> <div>(item.SUBJECT)</div>)
        return (
           <div>
            {course}
        </div>
        ); }   
        };
        export default CourseDetail;
````

Comment: Can you print console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data)); and show us the results? That would show all the fields in the object and tell us more about what is happening

Comment: like rander said, you are probably not handling the data correctly on the way back. you may need something like `response.data.json()` or something

Comment: If ```course``` is an object than you cannot ```.map()``` it. Mapping is reserved for arrays.

Comment: JSON.stringify(response.data) returns JSON data with values. But the const course= this.state.course.map() still returns error, TypeError: this.state.course.map is not a function.

Comment: Yea that's literally what I just said lol. Try this: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data))

Comment: The data is not array. After removing .map function, it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @HolyMoly mentioned in the comments, you may need to stringify the response as JSON as well before logging it depending on what the API is returning.  There's also a syntax error in your map function, you are using parentheses instead of curly braces to render the value.  Depending on the structure of your data response, something like this may work:

```
class CourseDetail extends Component {
          state={
             ID: this.props.match.params.ID,
             course:[]};


           componentDidMount() {
             axios.get('API\?{this.props.match.params.ID}')
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(res => {
               console.log("course="+res.data);
               this.setState({course: res.data})
             })
           }

        render(){
           //course is undefined below

        const course= this.state.course.map(item=> <div>{item.SUBJECT}</div>)
        return (
           <div>
            {course}
        </div>
        ); }   
        };
        export default CourseDetail;
```

This depends on whether or not the data you are mapping is an object or an array of course.  If it is in fact an object, you can map over the keys instead:

```
const course= Object.keys(this.state.course).map(item=> <div>{item.SUBJECT}</div>)
```

Comment: Thanks. The course is not array and cannot use map function. @ Rander Gabriel is correct. I need to parse JSON data.